# What is this kanji? It's too small for me to understand right now

Tags: kanji

If the image doesn't show up here is a link to it

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iy1un.png

[image: It's a little too small for me]

Comment: The kanji is a lie...

Answer (score 7):

It's 嘘 (うそ).​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​